# How to get image from SQL Server

Tags: image, sql-server-2005

I have table called `IMG` and there are columns `ID` and `Content` that holds pictures.

How is it possible to get picture from there?

I googled for this problem and what all I got was vb.net, c# and php - mysql.

Maybe someone can say what is the best and easiest way to get picture (sample, copy/paste code, program)?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using the `linq`, `dataset`, `entityFramework`, or pure query statement?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this (from d_r_w's answer):

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
   new SqlCommand("SELECT pic FROM imageTest WHERE pic_id = 1", 
     yourConnectionReference));

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
{
    Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
    data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pic"]);
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
    yourPictureBox.Image= Image.FromStream(mem);
}
```

Take alook at the [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084628/395659)

More options to do this:

- [Uploading / Downloading Pictures to / from a SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8681/Uploading-Downloading-Pictures-to-from-a-SQL-Serve)
- http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/imageimportexport/

I found [this post](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Articles/Storing-Images-in-Database/3/) regards PHP but with MySQL(you need to change the connection to your server):

```
<?php 
// image.php - by Hermawan Haryanto &lt;hermawan@dmonster.com&gt; 
// Example PHP Script, demonstrating Storing Image in Database 
// Detailed Information can be found at http://www.codewalkers.com 

// database connection 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") 
  OR DIE (mysql_error()); 
@mysql_select_db ("hermawan", $conn) OR DIE (mysql_error()); 
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE image_id=".$_GET["iid"]; 
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $conn); 
if (mysql_num_rows ($result)&gt;0) { 
  $row = @mysql_fetch_array ($result); 
  $image_type = $row["image_type"]; 
  $image = $row["image"]; 
  Header ("Content-type: $image_type"); 
  print $image; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe some explanations? What language is this? should I replace `yourConnectionReference` with my server IP, username, pass?

Comment: Sorry i didnt notices that there was no programming languange mentioned, this example is in C#, which language are you using actually?

Comment: I will try with cursor at first, if it does not work I will try PHP one:) Thanks!

Comment: does not work. there is need to download drivers for mssql connection

Comment: yep, i have read this article. There must be easier way to get pictures :) this is too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of reading and work found the solution!

Here it is! Works 100%

```
      Dim conn, sql, a, filename
      Dim dir 
      dir = "c:\images\" //saves files into this directory
      Dim fileObj
      Set fileObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Dim strStream
      Set strStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      Dim rstRecordset
      Set rstRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
      conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=yourserver;Integrated Security = SSPI","username","password"
      rstRecordset.Open "Select xxx, yyy, zzz from table (nolock) where xxx = '' order by xxx desc", conn    ', adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

      While Not rstRecordset.EOF  
     filename = rstRecordset.Fields(0) 
     er = 0

Do
    er = er+1
Loop While (fso.FileExists(dir & filename & "_" & er  & ".JPG"))  

    filename = dir & filename & "_" & er  & ".JPG"
    strStream.Type = 1
    strStream.Open
    strStream.Write rstRecordset.Fields(2).Value
    strStream.SaveToFile filename
    strStream.Close
        rstRecordset.MoveNext
    Wend
```

Here it is!

Comment: You made a hard job dude, this could be done easier with C#, +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks :) I am not familiar with C#. And found a very cool script on VB. Just made some corrections and it worked :)