# how to load an image from datagridview on mouse click into picturebox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, picturebox

I am working on a project where I have a list of images displayed through datagridview.
I want to load an image into picturebox when the particular image is clicked in datagridview.

My code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
        sql.Open()

        cmd = New SqlCommand("select pic from detail4 where id='" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value() & "'", sql)
        Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
        If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
            Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
            End Using
        End If

    End Sub
```

I get Out of memory exception..
What may be the problem.
pls help

Comment: what is `pic` column datatype?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load image from SQL Server into picture box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box)

Answer (score 0):

declare imagedata as object

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
cmd = New SqlCommand("select vchimage1  from producto where chrcodigoproducto='" & cCodProducto & "'", ClsCn.Cnx_Base)
Dim imagedata As Object
imagedata = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
'Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

If IsNothing(imagedata) Or IsDBNull(imagedata) Then

    ImgProducto.Visible = False
    mLoadPictureImage = False
Else
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length)
        ms.Write(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length)
        ImgProducto.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)

        mLoadPictureImage = True
    End Using
End If
```

www.jisoft-ingenieros.com