# display image from db alongside other webpage elements

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, image

A continuation of the question on [display (not download) image from db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642709/display-not-download-image-from-db)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="imgTest1.aspx.vb" Inherits="imgTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div style="background-color: aliceblue;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

            <div style="background-color: burlywood;">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="imgTest1.aspx?id=1" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class imgTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim strQuery As String = "select name, contentType, data from [imageTest] where id=1"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32("1")

            Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)

            If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("data"), Byte())
                Response.Buffer = True
                Response.Charset = ""
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" & dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString())
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
                Response.Flush()
                Response.End()
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CapstoneConnectionString1").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            sda.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            con.Close()
            sda.Dispose()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

I can now display the image on the aspx page but only the image is being displayed, all other web elements are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of one reason for this, given that following are true:

1. Page used to render contents is imgTest1.aspx as well as page used to return image is also imgTest1.aspx.
2. imgTest1.aspx is always invoked with query parameter, id.

because of this page always returns an image.

Can you change the code as follows and tell us how it works:

```
...
...
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="imgTest1.aspx?imageId=1" />
...
...
```

and in code-behind

```
If Request.QueryString("imageId") IsNot Nothing Then

    Dim strQuery As String = "select name, contentType, data from [imageTest] where id=1"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32("1")
```

Comment: thx, it works now. But what did it work after the name of the `QueryString` changes?