# read Image from Text Column in VB.Net Client from MSSQL Server

Tags: vb.net, image, text, binary, blob

It's a similar problem to [How to load image from SQL Server into picture box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box)

But in my case the **image column** in the DB is type of **"Text"**, which doesn't allow me to convert to a byte array:

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pic"]);
```

I have a table **mamedia** where images are stored in column **ma_bild**:
[image: table mamedia]

Now I need to read the image from column ma_bild using VB.Net - this is what I have so far:

[image: sql statements]

In VB.Net I can't convert the value of the text column to a Byte() Array

```
Dim byteBlobData1() As Byte = DirectCast(fotoTable.Rows(0).Item("ma_bild"), Byte())
```

-> error message: "System.String" can't be converted to type "System.Byte[]"

the **fotoTable DataTable** holds following values (only 1 row):

- **mabild_id:** 9a8d4fa7-57cd-4720-a397-158e2336d0ec
- **ma_id:**     3b686451-c9d3-4bcd-acf5-2fa407325837
- **ma_bild:**   ÿØÿà¬®2†Hç­IûEþÝš÷Å¨N–¹¸¸ºÛÁ7˜Hÿ... (goes on ~50000 characters)
- **ma_bild_textptr:** System.Byte[] = value of ptrval

Any ideas how the read the image information with the VB.Net client?

Last option probably would be to convert the image in the old foxpro client into an additional blob colomn.

***Edit: tried the Encoding**
In order to compare I did following steps:

- I stored a picture in the DB (via old FoxPro client)
- created a byte array of this picture from my harddrive (vb.net)
- read bytes from DB and encoded them (vb.net)

-> i.e.: System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fotoTable.Rows(0).Item("ma_bild"))

I tried all the Encoding Methods (UniCode, UTF7, UTF8, UTF32, BigEndianUnicode) and compared the byte arrays with the array from the original picture.

But only with Unicode/BigEndianUnicode the result was somewhat similar. The problem: the Unicode byte array is twice as long as the original byte array created directly from the picture.

-> every second byte from the unicode encoding is 0, so i created a new byte array with every second byte, but...
[image: table comparison]
... unfortunately some of the entries aren't correct...

this is the result:

[image: picture comparison]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load image from SQL Server into picture box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box).  Plus dozens of others.  Also, "text" either as a column type or tag doesnt come into play.

Comment: Load the column as a stream. And use `System.Text.Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(fotoTable.Rows(0).Item("ma_bild"))` to get the byte-array. Also, if it's a ntext field, you should use `System.Text.Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(fotoTable.Rows(0).Item("ma_bild"))` OR `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fotoTable.Rows(0).Item("ma_bild"))`

Comment: I tried the Encoding - find new information in the "Edit Section" of my question