# How to bind an image into picture box from SQL Server along with a textbox and combo box on C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, binding

So I have a table called Bicycle inside BikeStore database on sql server, consists of the following columns:
BID, BName, Description, BType, Brand, Origin, Price, Stock, BImage

Successfully bind all textboxes and one combo box with my data from sql server just by clicking cells on datagridview. Below is the code:

```
private void dg1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        bidTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        bnameTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        bdescrichTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        typeCB.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        brandTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        originTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        priceTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        stockTxt.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
```

But it still generates an error everytime I tried to load the image too. Here's the code:

```
        sqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BImage FROM Bicycle WHERE BID = " + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + "", sqlconn);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        byte[] mydata = new byte[0];
        da.Fill(ds, "Bicycle");
        DataRow myrow;
        myrow = ds.Tables["Bicycle"].Rows[8];
        mydata = (byte[])myrow["BImage"];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
        BikePic.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        sqlconn.Close();
}
```

What did I do wrong?

I'm new at this.

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line?

Comment: SqlException was unhandled: Invalid column B001 on da.Fill(ds, "Bicycle");

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If it just about only retrieving the BLOB on that query then you could do something more simple :

```
// SqlConnection creation and opening omitted
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BImage FROM Bicycle WHERE BID = " + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + "", sqlconn))
{
  byte[] mydata = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
  BikePic.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Also you might want to dispose of `stream` after creating the `Image` control but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Still generates error unfortunately. "SqlException was unhandled: Invalid column B001"

Comment: Then you must analyze the sql query to find out where does this column "B001" come from. Try using the SQL Server Profiler if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Add **single quotation mark** on the SqlCommand line between the **blockquote** as it'll search up the ID you looking for,  like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BImage FROM Bicycle WHERE BID = '" + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + "'", sqlconn);
```

Below is the code **before modified**. See the difference?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BImage FROM Bicycle WHERE BID = " + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + "", sqlconn);
```

Haha silly me. **Thanks anyway guys!**