Read an image from the database and use in an Image control
I am getting an image from SQL Server as object and trying to save it in a property of type Image. But I don't know how to convert an object to an image. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
ProductsModel.cs
using System.Drawing;

namespace Nettbutikk.Models
{
    public class ProductsModel
    {
        public Image ProductImage { get; set; }
    }
}

ProductsController.cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Products(ProductsModel objProductsModel)
{
    string conStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Nettbutikk; Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    string qury = "select * from products";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qury, con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        //objProductsModel.ProductImage = dr.GetValue(1).Value as System.Drawing.Image;
        //objProductsModel.ProductImage = System.Drawing.Image(dr.GetValue(1));

        return View(objProductsModel);
    }

    return View(objProductsModel);
}


Use a buffer or stream

There are loads of examples available on the internet... e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084590/how-to-load-image-from-sql-server-into-picture-box

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616751/10024425. If you find it useful, give it an upvote to make it easier for other to find in the future.
